# Iphone Binary submitting tutorial?

Tags: iphone

Alright I got my iphone application completly done and have done all the steps to get it submitted except for uploading the binary. Is there a step by step tutorial out therefor getting the binary all ready for uploading cause I'm completly lost. I just signed up for the developers program last night and am not sure if I need to download something to be able to publish my application or something.

Comment: If you just became a developer, that means you probably haven't built on the iPhone yet. Do this as SOON as you can. Your app will almost guaranteed perform differently on the iPhone, since it has limited processor and memory.

Comment: Try reading the guide in the following tutorial

http://stackoverflow.com/a/16747740/846372

Answer (score 4):

I think it's a late response to this question; but after you've figured out the provisioning profile, and code signings, you must do the following:

1. Create the app in http://itunesconnect.apple.com > Manage Your Applications > Add New App
   You must follow the steps to prepare things to upload your binary, and after finishing this, make it "ready for upload". You can read the [iTunesconnect developer guide](http://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf) to see how to do all these.
2. Connect your iDevice, and put the scheme running on the device instead of the simulator.
3. go to `Product > Archive` from Xcode menu.
4. The Organizer window will be opened automatically when archiving is done. Press `Validate` button, and proceed with your developer account ID.
5. Follow the steps and continue till the validation is done successfully.
6. Press `Distribute` button and again follow the wizard and wait till the binary is uploaded.

Comment: This should be the chosen answer. Thank you so much for posting this step by step guide. I couldn't find a way to do it, I have read lots of different pages on iTunes connect with no luck. I had no idea I had to submit my app via XCode itself, but thanks to you, I know that now.

Answer (score 0):

Go look in the iphone developer portal or Itunes connect

Comment: The actually have a really nice guide in iTunes connect.  You can find it on the page where you submit your applications.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create and download various certificates from the developer portal.
[This tutorial](http://adeem.me/blog/2009/04/04/list-guideline-for-submitting-iphone-application-to-apple-store/) looks pretty good, there's more at Apple's site too.

My main advice is to expect to wait a week or two after you submit for your app to go live, and to be aware that you'll probably think of something you wish you had changed during that time.

Answer (score 0):

For your specific problem there is a specific solution: use 'Appplication Loader' to submit the binary, when you already done the rest in itunes connect. More [here](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/tools/application-loader.html)